Data source name not found, and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)
i have created cron job on linux machine in pyodbc. While manually trigger it is running well but while running cron job it is giving an error Data source name not found, and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect). Please help
We have tried checking System DSN and restart then exporting and all still issue not resolved. we want solution to run the job on linux using schedule.
